# Inserting external text file into input element

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I have a text file here named "test.txt".
The contents of this file are 12, 14, 16 and 18, each on their own line.
I want to take these numbers, and read them into four different input elements on my HTML code. The HTML elements are as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="p1" class="p1" readonly>
<input type="text" id="p2" class="p2" readonly>
<input type="text" id="p3" class="p3" readonly>
<input type="text" id="p4" class="p4" readonly>
```

I don't have any javascript or anything of that sort yet.

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: wait what ? not sure what you want.

Comment: Define 'external file'. Is it stored on your web server, a different web server, or a user's computer?

Comment: I want to take each of those numbers, and then insert each one into the seperate elements

Comment: it's currently on my computer, but I want to move it to a server at some point

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you want to read the numbers into input elements. It doesn't sound good. You probably want to display them on a page and add some styles. You can use the code below as a starting point.

```
function readTextFile() {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            var allNumbs = rawFile.responseText;

            var arrayOfLines = allNumbs.split("\n");

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++) {

                var element = document.createElement("p");

                element.id = "p" + (i + 1);
                element.className = "p" + (i + 1);
                element.innerHTML = arrayOfLines[i];
                document.body.appendChild(element);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send();
}
readTextFile();
```

My file.txt looks like this.

```
12
15
16
17
28
```

The html output:

```
<p id="p1" class="p1">12</p>
<p id="p2" class="p2">15</p>
<p id="p3" class="p3">16</p>
<p id="p4" class="p4">17</p>
<p id="p5" class="p5">28</p>
```

Comment: I think this will work. The only reason I had the input elements was for styling purposes but I can just overlay the text over them.

Comment: Yep. Just upvoted it but don't have enough reputation so it's not publicly shown.... anyways- i found a problem with the paragraph solution. it won't be centered properly throughout my input element as I can have different amounts of characters in there. any way you know to fix that?